# Formating a random number in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net-2010

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim generator As New Random
    Dim myRand As Integer
    myRand = generator.Next(1000000000, 9999999999)
    Label1.Text =  ???
End Sub
```

This code generates a 10 digit number though it does not format the number they way i want.I want the format to be
123 456 7890
How could i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a **custom number format string to format the number as you want it. You can do so by passing a format string into the `ToString` method of every number.

For more on custom number formats go to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Try the following, this format works just fine in C#:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim generator As New Random
    Dim myRand As Integer
    myRand = generator.Next(1000000000, 9999999999)
    Label1.Text =  myRand.ToString("### ### ####")
End Sub
```